# Firefox on X11 -- Can I use the multitouch gestures with a touchscreen?

Tags: firefox, xorg, touchscreen

Firefox has support for some multitouch gestures on desktop (pinch and swipe at least) -- is there any way to get them working with a touchscreen right now, or will they only work with a touchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox for desktop on Linux doesn't currently support X11's multitouch extension.

[The bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=711711) tracking support for this suggests the feature is dependent on Firefox moving from GTK2 to GTK3 (which as of July 22nd is done in [Nightly](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/05f6b5bc5b4b) and as of August 14th is also present in [Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/42.0a2/auroranotes/)).